# Dificuldade em criar Function no oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, funções, pl-sql

Estou tentando criar uma função no oracle, mas estou com dificuldade em criar o retorno dela.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function simple_function(
     state             VARCHAR2,
     city_id           NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS ret VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    SELECT 'XXX ' || state || ' - ' || city_id INTO ret FROM DUAL;
    RETURN ret;
END;
```

[image: ORA-ERROR]

Quando eu tento a versão simplificada, funciona

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function simple_function(
     state             VARCHAR2,
     city_id           NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 
BEGIN
    RETURN 'That''s All Folks!';
END;
```

Vi algumas [documentações](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/r0054067.html), e não sei o que estou fazendo de errado quanto a variável de retorno.
Há algumas funções similares no sistema, e elas funcionam, mas o retorno é **NUMBER**, esse que eu preciso é um retorno **VARCHAR2**, eu não sei se há algum diferencial para esse caso.

Comment: No parâmetro você esta passando state  e esta usando a variável uf, que não esta declarada.

Comment: @Confundir Desculpe, eu estava traduzindo para postar no stackoverflow, mas achei que ficaria mais simples se postasse aqui. a nomenclatura é a mesma no meu exemplo. Se vc rodar o exemplo, com as variaveis iguais, o erro vai ser o mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você cria uma função no `Oracle` você deve informar se o parâmetro é de entrada ou saída. No seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function simple_function(
   state IN VARCHAR2,
   city_id IN NUMBER
  )
RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS ret VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'XXX ' || state || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(city_id)
    INTO ret
    FROM DUAL;

  RETURN ret;
END;
```

> [`Functions`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php)
>
> When you create a procedure or function, you may define parameters. There are three types of parameters that can be declared:
>
> - **IN** - The parameter can be referenced by the procedure or function. The value of the parameter can not be overwritten by the procedure or function.
> - **OUT** - The parameter can not be referenced by the procedure or function, but the value of the parameter can be overwritten by the procedure or function.
> - **IN OUT** - The parameter can be referenced by the procedure or function and the value of the parameter can be overwritten by the procedure or function.

Em tradução livre:

> Quando você cria uma procedure ou função, você pode definir parâmetros. Existem três tipos de parâmetros que podem ser declarados:
>
> - **IN** - O parâmetro pode ser referenciado pela procedure ou function. O valor do parâmetro não pode ser sobrescrito pela procedure ou function.
> - **OUT** - O parâmetro não pode ser referenciado pela procedure ou function, mas o valor do parâmetro pode ser sobrescrito pela procedure ou function.
> - **IN OUT** - O parâmetro pode ser referenciado pela procedure ou function e o valor do parâmetro pode ser sobrescrito pela procedure ou function.

Comment: Lembrando que este select não seria necessário bastaria atribuir o valor à variável.

Comment: @Motta como que faz?

Comment: ret := 'XXX ' || state || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(city_id);

Comment: Valeu @Motta, estava curioso quanto a isso